# manipulating a json array with php

Tags: php, json

This is my json array contained in a file name test.json :

```
   [{name:'xyz',code:'345'},{name:'bcd',code:'123'},{name:'jkl',code:'432'}]
```

I have to echo the code of first name,please tell me how.

Comment: Have you even googled this? There are many, many examples.

Comment: no I am still clueless

Answer (score 3):

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('test.json'), true);
foreach ($json as $curr) {
    echo $curr['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$array = json_decode(file_get_contents('test.json'), true);
$length = count($array);
for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
    echo $array[$i]['name'] . '<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my first StackOverflow post so I hope this is ok.
You can do this with PHP's json_decode() and file_get_contents().
Except I had errors with your JSON but it worked when I quoted(") the keys like:

```
[{"name":"xyz","code":"345"},{"name":"bcd","code":"123"},{"name":"jkl","code":"432"}]
```

This is my PHP:

```
<?php
$contents = file_get_contents("test.json");

$array = json_decode($contents, true);

echo $array[0]['name'];
```

I hope this helps you.

Edit: I re-read the question after submitting and realised you wanted all the first names. and not the first 'name' in the array.

```
<?php
$contents = file_get_contents("test.json");
$array = json_decode($contents, true);
foreach($array as $value){
    echo $value['name'];
}
```